# Simple calculator issues (Not outputting answers)

Tags: c++

just started reading a C++ book and one of the practice problems was to write a small calculator that takes as input one of the four arithmetic operations, the two arguments to those operations, and then prints out the results.

Sadly, the program works up until the user inputs the arithmetic option.
So if I chose to do multiplication, id write "Multiplication" and it was just stay there and not do anything after. 
[Image of the problem im having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVYCm.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    // Simple calculator program

    // Declaring three variables
    float numberOne;
    float numberTwo;
    string operationOption;

    // Asking the user which two numbers he/she will use
    cout << "Enter the first number you would like to apply a arithmetic operation to: ";
    cin >> numberOne;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Now enter the second number: ";
    cin >> numberTwo;
    cin.ignore();

    // Using cin to input users selection
    cout << "Enter the operation you want to perform." << endl;
    cout << "The options you have are: " << endl;
    cout << "Multiplication, Subraction, Division and Addition: " << endl;
    cin >> operationOption;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    // Where it all happens
    if ( operationOption == "Multiplication" ) {
        cout << "The first number multiplied by the second number is: " << numberOne * numberTwo << endl;
    } else if ( operationOption == "Division" ) {
        cout << "The first number divided by the second number is: " << numberOne / numberTwo << endl;
    } else if ( operationOption == "Subtraction" ) {
        cout << "The first number subtracted by the second number is: " << numberOne - numberTwo << endl;
    } else if ( operationOption == "Addition ") {
        cout << "The first number added to the second number is: " << numberOne + numberTwo << endl;
    } else {
            cout << "You entered an invalid option.";
    };

}
```

Comment: ignore the ; at the end of the else statement, i removed that and still receive the same problem.

Comment: Try to remove the `cin.get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove line :

```
cin.get();
```

will solve your problem